# Mistakenly inserted date in month field sql how to change

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, date-formatting

Unfortunately I inserted a date as dd-mm-yyyy in sql but it assumed it as mm-dd-yyyy Now more than 50 fields are like this how can I change this? I found an exception as invalid date when I was taking report by date that more than 12. Now I want to change all of the inserted fields without losting it

Comment: You will have to tell us which RDBMS you are using, as date functions vary a lot.

Comment: I've mentioned MSSQL 2008 R2

Comment: What is the **datatype** of the column involved?

Comment: Note that dates are stored in the database without a format. The database just knows what format is the default and applies that when accepting a date or outputting one. It seems that your database is set to dd/mm/yyyy format. You might want to change that.

Comment: Actually now the database format is yyyy/dd/mm. I cannot change every rows so I'm asking is there anyway to simplify this

Comment: Dates don't have formats, they are stored as two integer values. The format you changed affects string formating, not the date values. The database makes no assumptions about formats if you enter *date* values. If you enter *text* values, it will try to translate them using information like the locale of the client application and the table's collation. You should find and delete the wrong rows then insert them again as *dates* instead of strings.

Comment: @Venkat The ISO format for dates is 'YYYYMMDD', so you may be able to fix the affected rows ONLY by setting the dates to `SomeColumn=CONVERT(datetime,SomeColumn,112)`. Make sure you update *only* the affected rows to avoid mangling the entire table

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET dateColumn = MONTH(dateColumn) + "-" + DAY(vdateColumn) + "-" + YEAR(dateColumn)
```

I hope this work even though I didn't test it myself. Please use a WHERE clause to limit the update only to the impacted rows.

Comment: Dates don't have formats. The format you use is NOT the invariant format so you'll probably mangle all values. You force a conversion from date to some string, then convert that back to date using an unspecified format (actually, the one defined by the database's collation).

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET yourDateColumn = Convert(datetime,yourDateColumn,101)
```

Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: This will make things *worse* if the fields are `datetime` valued. Dates don't have formats. By converting the dates to strings and storing them back into the date field (implicitly converting them), either you'll put back the same value or you'll swap days and months for *all* rows

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked but finally I reset it manually by c# console

```
Console.WriteLine("Changing Orderdate");
        Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        List<string> date = new List<string>();
        List<string> no = new List<string>();

        int i = 0;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DATEPART(yyyy,orderdate) as y, DATEPART(mm,orderdate) as m, DATEPART(dd,orderdate) as d, bno from bill", con);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            date.Add(dr["y"].ToString() + "-" + dr["d"].ToString() + "-" + dr["m"].ToString());
            no.Add(dr["bno"].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();

        foreach (var a in date)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inserting: " + date[i] + " With " + no[i]);
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("update bill set orderdate = '" + date[i] + "' where bno = " + no[i], con);
            con.Open();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Order date changing completed \n\n");
```

Thank you for sharing your precious time thanks friends